# Find element's width, not maxwidth

Tags: javascript, width, css

How do I find the width of an  element?

I have maxwidth set to 100px & width set to "auto". I'm attempting to find its exact width dynamically which could be <100px.

I tried these options:
element.offSetWidth, element.style.width, created a region through Dom.getRegion & pulled width..

However, all the above options return 100px as width.

Any non-jquery based solution please?

-Vidi

Comment: Try `offsetWidth` with a lowercase `s`, instead of `offSetWidth`

Comment: Guys, thanks so much for all your responses. offsetWidth indeed works! There were 2 <a> tags that were rendered besides each other & apparently my logic to pull the second one was incorrect, so it was always alerting me back with the first element's width which was 100px. Really appreciate all your time :) -Vidi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`offsetWidth` really should work. [**Proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/n23g5/). Try resizing the "Result" window, and you'll see the `div` update in size.

```
document.getElementById("id").offsetWidth;
```

*Make sure you use `offsetWidth`, not `offSetWidth` (note capitalization).*

Comment: Guys, thanks so much for all your responses. offsetWidth indeed works! There were 2 <a> tags that were rendered besides each other & apparently my logic to pull the second one was incorrect, so it was always alerting me back with the first element's width which was 100px. Really appreciate all your time :) -Vidi

Comment: @vidi, not a problem! If this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? (Click the outline of the checkmark by this answer.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById(ID_OF_ELEMENT).offsetWidth should work

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("id").clientWidth` should work

Answer (score 0):

add a float or make it inline

```
<style type="text/css">
        #test_max_width{
            max-width : 100px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="test_max_width">s</div>
    <input type="button" value="more" id="addcontent"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var output = document.getElementById( "test_max_width" );
        document.getElementById( "addcontent" ).onclick= function  (  ) {
            output.innerHTML += output.innerHTML;
            console.log ( output.offsetWidth );
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Guys, thanks so much for all your responses. offsetWidth indeed works! There were 2 <a> tags that were rendered besides each other & apparently my logic to pull the second one was incorrect, so it was always alerting me back with the first element's width which was 100px. Really appreciate all your time :)

-Vidi